# python tkinter error: unknown option "-font" for LabelFrame

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to configure my `LabelFrame` widget in `tkinter` but I'm getting an error.

Here is my code where it says the error is.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Labelframe
    
class RMS:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Student Result Management System")
        self.root.geometry("1920x1080+0+0")
        self.root.config(bg="white")
        
        #===MENUE===#
        M_Frame=Labelframe(self.root,text="Menus",font=("times new roman",15),bg="white")
        M_Frame.place(x=10,y=70,width=1340,height=80)
               
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = RMS(root)                                                                                              
    root.mainloop()
```

It is showing error: unknown option "-font"

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Projects\Python\StackOverflow\teest.py", line 23, in <module>
    obj = RMS(root)
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Projects\Python\StackOverflow\teest.py", line 17, in __init__
    M_Frame = Labelframe(self.root, text="Menus", font=("Arial", 15), bg="white")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 773, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::labelframe", kw)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 552, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2601, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-font"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Give us the full traceback so we know which line is the problem.

Comment: Give us the full traceback so we know which line is the problem

Answer (score 3):

There is no font for `LabelFrame`. You are using `tkinter.ttk` so you can use `Style()` for what you want.
Use this code to configure your `LabelFrame`:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("my_style", font=("times new roman", 15), background="white")
label_frame = ttk.Labelframe(root, text="This is a test!", style="my_style")
```